# Adding Kubernetes to visual studio project in "container orchestration support"

Tags: docker, visual-studio, kubernetes, containers

I have to deploy my microservice, that is composed by 2 container.
I noticed that on visual studio you can add container orchestration suppor, but I have only docker-compose on that window, is it possible to add other supports? Like K8s?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can debug remotely with Kubernetes on Visual Studio. You will have to create a cluster and then integrate it in your environment. You can find the procedure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/bridge/bridge-to-kubernetes-vs) on Microsoft docs.